# Is it okay to pass non-ref objects as refs if they are contained within a ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I have a ref that contains an object that contains two refs:

```
function useFocusTargets() {
  const from = useRef();
  const to = useRef();
  const focusTargets = useRef({from : from, to: to});  
  return focusTargets.current;
}
```

I pass the two inner refs around to components to get access to their DOM elements. It worked, but I changed it so that the two inner refs were just regular objects instead `useRef({from : {}, to: {}})` and it still seemed to work...but I got this warning:

```
Unexpected ref object provided for input. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().
```

I'm assuming that what I did isn't proper. But I can't figure out why. It seems to be working just fine and it makes sense to me (`focusTargets` is a ref so it's preserved so the `{from : {}, to :{}}` inside `focusTargets` should also be preserved).

Is it okay to do what I did, and if not, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render multiple times the same component and all instances have the same state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995986/how-to-render-multiple-times-the-same-component-and-all-instances-have-the-same)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, the idea of the singleton seems really useful. But I think my question's a little different? I'm passing my refs down because I want the child components to give something to the parent. Since the things I'm passing are the objects inside my ref, I was wondering if those inner objects had to be refs or if they could just be regular objects.

Comment: Are you passing down `focusTargets` (which is a ref) or `focusTargets.current` (which is a plain object)?  I would need to see more code in order to debug this.

Comment: I pass down focusTargets.current.to